# How to add sendMessage() function in Java?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

i am using https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity for learning but there is stuck for me that sendMessage() is not properly written by me so can you help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy buddy, the sendMessage() method should be written by you receiving a View as you can see in the example, it will allow you to use this method directly in the button. You must call this method on the button "send" inside your .xml file using the android:onClick="sendMessage()".

It will be something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent); 
}
}
```

And the button inside the xml file like this:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage()"/>
```

Good luck!!!